# Two-sample unpaired hypothesis test of ROC AUC?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, auc

I wish to calculate the p-value to reject the null hypothesis that the AUC, i.e. area under a receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve, is equal between two independent samples.  That is, given AUC1 from sample 1, and AUC2 from sample 2, how to compute the p-value to reject the null hypothesis that AUC1=AUC2?

(I want to do it in python.)

I see that one can calculate the confidence interval of AUC by assuming it is normally distributed (see [here](https://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/roc-curve-classification-table/auc-confidence-interval/), [here](https://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Confidence_Intervals_for_the_Area_Under_an_ROC_Curve.pdf), and the original Hanley and McNeil [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C24&q=hanley%20and%20mcneil%201982&btnG=&oq=hanley%20and%20mc)).

The formulas (in python) are:

```
q0 = auc * (1-auc)
q1 = auc / (2-auc) - auc*auc
q2 = 2 * auc * auc / (1+auc) - auc*auc
# n1=number of positive examples
# n2=number of negative examples
stderr = math.sqrt((q0 + (n1-1) * q1 + (n2-1) * q2) / (n1*n2) )
# 95% confidence interval: z_alpha_over_2=1.96
c95 = 1.96 * stderr
```

I also see that [this calculator](http://vassarstats.net/roc_comp.html) (if you "view source") is using those formulas to calculate the standard error of each of the two auc's and compare them using [some numerical approximation to the normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357347/18612).  In Javascript:

```
sediff = sqrt(sqr(se_a)+sqr(se_b));
z = (auc_a-auc_b)/sediff;
z = Math.abs(z);
p2 = (((((.000005383*z+.0000488906)*z+.0000380036)*z+.0032776263)*z+.0211410061)*z+.049867347)*z+1;
p2 = Math.pow(p2,-16);
```

I think p2 is the p-value of the two-tailed test.

Does this computation seem reasonable?

Is there an easier way to state it if I have the cumulative distribution of the normal distribution (like [scipy.stats.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).cdf)?

Is there an easier way to compute this p-value?

**EDIT**: [DeLong et al](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C24&q=DeLong++comparing+the+areas+under+two+or+more+correlated+receiver+operating+characteristic+curves) perhaps answers this question, but it's not easy to understand.  I hoped it would be easier for this special case (two independent samples).

Comment: I think you listed a good amount of resources. To add on, I found [this blog](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2020/02/04/comparing-aucs-of-machine-learning-models-with-delongs-test/) quite useful in explaining the DeLong's test. There is an implementation of AUC test in R's pROC package. For python, there is an approximation implemented [here](https://github.com/yandexdataschool/roc_comparison).